Using GAMLSS modeling with p-splines in dredge
I have a GAMLSS model in which I have a formula as such: "y ~ pb(age, by=c(sex, dataset))"
When I use dredge it doesn't "try", for example, "y ~ pb(age, by=sex)". That is it doesn't try all the different interactions with the p-spline
Is there any way to make it do that?
